# null values appearing in stringified js object (using json2.js and FF)

Tags: javascript, json, firefox

i have a js object a which contains several other objects within it (say b, c, ..., z). suppose before serializing it through json2, i delete objects b and c from my objects using delete. checking in firebug reveals that the objects b and c and the indexes b and c was removed. however, checking the serialized json string shows nulls where the deleted objects were. i used the following code to generate the json string.

```
var json_data = JSON.stringify(template, null, 2);
```

am i missing something in the function call? or is there a bug when used with FF?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't understand your question right, but I couldn't reproduce the problem in either chrome or firefox (4)

```
var obj = {p1: 'test1', p2: 'test2'};
console.log(obj);
delete obj.p1;
console.log(obj);
JSON.stringify(obj);
```

> Object { p1="test1", p2="test2"}
>
> Object { p2="test2"}
>
> "{"p2":"test2"}"

Do you have an exemple of your problem ?